# how to visualize the coefficients from different models in just one plot?

Tags: r

I have 2 different datasets. To each one i apply the same plm regression. I would like to know how can i visualize, in the same plot, the estimated coefficients of each model.

```
mainstream <- plm(log(sum_plays) ~  cancel_public_events + close_public_transport + internationaltravel + restrictions_on_gatherings + school_closing + stay_at_home_requirements + workplace_closing + new_cases_per_million + new_deaths_per_million +
data = top200, model = "within")

long_tail <- plm(log(sum_plays) ~  cancel_public_events + close_public_transport + internationaltravel + restrictions_on_gatherings + school_closing + stay_at_home_requirements + workplace_closing + new_cases_per_million + new_deaths_per_million +
data = bottom, model = "within")
```

I can make the plot for each individual model, however i want to have the info of this both plots in just one. Probably differentiate the coefficients by color (i.e coefficients from "mainstream" in red and the coefficients from "longtail" in blue)

```
a <- plot_model(long_tail, transform = NULL, show.values = TRUE, value.offset =.3, terms = c("workplace_closing" , "stay_at_home_requirements", "school_closing", "close_public_transport", "internationaltravel", "restrictions_on_gatherings", "cancel_public_events"), title = "Coefficients for Long-Tail Music Consumption")


b <- plot_model(mainstream, transform = NULL, show.values = TRUE, value.offset =.3, terms = c("workplace_closing" , "stay_at_home_requirements", "school_closing", "close_public_transport", "internationaltravel", "restrictions_on_gatherings", "cancel_public_events"), title = "Coefficients for Long-Tail Music Consumption")
```

Comment: check out the `dotwhisker` package.

Comment: hey @BenBolker i follow your ideia but i get an error message of: "Error: Sorry, `model_parameters()` does currently not work for objects of class 'plm'"

Comment: can you post a [mcve] please?  What I have in mind is `library(dotwhisker); dwplot(list(mainstream, long_tail))`.  What did you try?